# Where Does "Toad for Oracle" saves the my sql queries from editor

Tags: toad

I need to copy my sql queries to my own drive, I had created these queries using editor in toad for oracle 12.6..Can some one please help me out where is the folder that toad the my queries.?

Problem is that my toad is not working anymore and I need to re-install it so before that I want to get my saved sql files to my own drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queries are saved in a file called:

- **SAVEDSQL.xml**

This file is (in my case) under:

- **C:\Program Files\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\User Files**

Answer (score 0):

Your saved SQL is stored in SavedSQL.dat. Its location will be... %APPDATA%\Dell\Toad for Oracle\12.6\SavedSQL.dat

If you back that file up you can restore your current installation to a "new install" state without actually reinstalling. Toad does nothing with its installation folder and the likelihood that something is corrupt with the installation is slim. Your user configuration files may have gone squirrely though. To restore your config files choose "Copy User Settings..." from the Utilities menu. Select the option to rest to a clean set. Toad will restart. Close Toad and copy your backed up savedsql.dat back to %APPDATA%\Dell\Toad for Oracle\12.6\SavedSQL.dat.

If you provide info on what it means for Toad to stop working there may be another issue we can resolve to save you from trashing your config files.

Answer (score 0):

SavedSQL.xml contains lots of cryptic looking info about connections, but no scripts.
SavedSQL.dat does not exist

I should mention that I am using version 12.10 Toad for Oracle Xpert